# Cascading Dropdown Infopath and viewing columns in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have been able to create a Cascading dropdown menu in Infopath Designer 2013 and was able to link it to a list.

For Example: The user will select "Country" and a dropdown menu of correlating "Cities" will appear. However once these are selected the respective columns in the Sharepoint 2013 list do not actually say what the Country or Cities actually are but display Integers instead.

Any help on how to make the sharepoint list display the actual name of the selection rather than the integer will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this because initially I had the "Cities" list as a look up column linking to it's country. This value was an Integer but this was quickly solved when I deleted that column in the "Cities" list and made it a Text column instead.

Hope this helps anyone in the same boat as me.